# In XPath notation, how does the expression //*[self::SOME_LABEL] differ from //SOME_LABEL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

At work, I am updating some XSLT transformation code, and in some places a previous programmer used the former expression to retrieve the value of an element named SOME_LABEL from an XML document.

Both //*[self::SOME_LABEL] and //SOME_LABEL forms seem to produce the same result node set.

The original programmer(s) are no longer working here to ask, but in my research, I have not been able to find any reason the former is preferable to the latter.  I certainly don't want to break working code, but the second form is much more readable and self-documenting (maintainability).

I tend to use it to accomplish the same result in new code I am writing and would like to make all such expressions consistent; failing to do so leaves the code a bizarre mixture of both.

Is there any reason I shouldn't change all the occurrences of the first form to the second?

Answer (score 2):

> In XPath notation, how does the expression `//*[self::SOME_LABEL]` differ from `//SOME_LABEL`?

It differs in readability. Otherwise it is equivalent.

One reason to use the `self` axis in XPath 1.0 is when you want to select a group of different element nodes at a given path location that is longish to type and that you don't want to repeat:

```
/some/longish[@and='complicated']/path/then[ self::a or self::b or self::c ]
```

This is not the case in your example. So you could make the change to ease maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

The default axis is child:: , so it is different in meaning. The following graphic is by Crane Softwrights.

[image: Valid XHTML].

However it is true that //*[self::X] will match the same nodes as //X . So yes, make this substitution.